# Is there a regularized Ricci flow which will not generate singularity?

Tags: regularization, ricci-flow

Define Hamilton's Ricci flow as
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} g_{ij}(t) = -2 R_{ij}(t)$$

**Q:** Does there exist a regularized Ricci flow like

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} g_{ij} = -2  F(g_{ij}, R_{ij})R_{ij}$$

Such that the singularity like neckpinch will not occur during the evolution?

Comment: May I ask which dimension you are in? Ricci flow in dimension 2 should have no neck pinches.

Comment: 3,4,...dimensions